# Adding a Button to JTable before creating the table

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on Reflections and Swings for my project. Using reflections I need to get the information of a particular method, and populate a JTable based on its structure.

The table has the following feature:
 **Some columns will be named based on the parameter type present in the selected method.**[image]

Its the same structre for all the primitive data types(int,float,double,String,long,boolean), only the column names get Changed based on the data type.

The problem I face is when there is a User Defined object inside the method parameter. 
In that scenario , I want a JButton instead of empty cell in the row (under that parameter type).

I tried learning**TableCellRenderer** and **CellEditor** but nothing helped me because all the tutorials i have seen are based on a Static data(rows and columns). In my case both rows and columns have to be generated dynamically and I need to create the JTable based on my data(dynamically).

I'm trying the following code:

```
rowData = new Object[1][colData.length];
        rowData[0][0] = "";
        rowData[0][colData.length - 1] = "";

        int i = 1;
        for (Class tempClass : paramType) {
            if (tempClass.getSimpleName().equals("int")
            //Primitives
                    || tempClass.getSimpleName().equals("float")
                    || tempClass.getSimpleName().equals("long")
                    || tempClass.getSimpleName().equals("double")
                    || tempClass.getSimpleName().equals("boolean")
                    || tempClass.getSimpleName().equals("String")){
                rowData[0][i] = "";
            }
            else{
            //User Defined obj
                rowData[0][i] = new JButton();
            }

            i++;
        }
```

But the output i'm getting is something like this:
[image]

Kindly help me and provide me a hint or kind of tutorial so that i can proceed with this problem. I'm working on the swings for the first time.

Comment: If you don't get help soon, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: since i'm using reflections , this particular code is dependent entirely on another project.

Comment: Wishing you success in solving it then.

Answer (score 1):

The pictures you posted don't help me since the text to too small for me to read so I'm not sure what you are trying to demonstrate. Make sure the data is readable when you post a question is the data is in fact important to the question.

> nothing helped me because all the tutorials i have seen are based on a Static data(rows and columns).

Maybe this example will help. It shows how to dynamically determine the renderer/editor for a cell based on the class of the data in the cell:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TablePropertyEditor extends JFrame
{
    public TablePropertyEditor()
    {
        String[] columnNames = {"Type", "Value"};
        Object[][] data =
        {
            {"String", "I'm a string"},
            {"Date", new Date()},
            {"Integer", new Integer(123)},
            {"Double", new Double(123.45)},
            {"Boolean", Boolean.TRUE}
        };

        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames)
        {
            private Class editingClass;

            public TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer(int row, int column)
            {
                editingClass = null;
                int modelColumn = convertColumnIndexToModel(column);

                if (modelColumn == 1)
                {
                    Class rowClass = getModel().getValueAt(row, modelColumn).getClass();
                    return getDefaultRenderer( rowClass );
                }
                else
                    return super.getCellRenderer(row, column);
            }

            public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int column)
            {
                editingClass = null;
                int modelColumn = convertColumnIndexToModel(column);

                if (modelColumn == 1)
                {
                    editingClass = getModel().getValueAt(row, modelColumn).getClass();
                    return getDefaultEditor( editingClass );
                }
                else
                    return super.getCellEditor(row, column);
            }

            //  This method is also invoked by the editor when the value in the editor
            //  component is saved in the TableModel. The class was saved when the
            //  editor was invoked so the proper class can be created.

            public Class getColumnClass(int column)
            {
                return editingClass != null ? editingClass : super.getColumnClass(column);
            }
        };

        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        getContentPane().add( scrollPane );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TablePropertyEditor frame = new TablePropertyEditor();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Edit:

> instead to get a Button, what should i keep

There is no default renderer/editor for a button, so you will need to store a custom object and create a custom renderer/editor.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for more information.

Then you have to tell the table about your custom objects with code like:

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(CustomObject.class, new CustomRenderer());
table.setDefaultEditor(CustomObject.class, new CustomRenderer());
```

You might be able to use the [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) as the renderer/editor.

Comment: To get a checkbox you have kept **Boolean.TRUE**, instead to get a Button, what should i keep.

Comment: Your browser has a right click option to open an image in another tab.  This will show you the full size of the images.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc, its disabled in IE. Anyway, we should not need to take that extra step.